# Reduce select size: size adjust to filter options

Tags: html, css, select

I have a simple problem I do not know how to manage
I have a simple select that receive a full list of option
I use JS to filter the shown option based on another select (source: http://jsfiddle.net/pz9cjmLg/5/)

when I click on the right arrow of the select, list is shown
first option is empty
but I would like to adjust the size of the list to the size of options shown and not the the total size of the list (see picture below)

[image]
I try to use size="3" (for example) but it is not what I need

**html**

```
        <form id="form_reallocation" method="POST" class="post-form">
            {% csrf_token %}
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1"><strong>{% trans 'Patient code number :' %}</strong></label>
                <select required name="patients" class="form-control" id="patients" data-patient-url="{% url 'randomization:patient' %}">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    {% for patient in patients %}
                        <option value="{{ patient.ran_log_sit }}/{{ patient.ran_num }}">{{ patient.ran_num }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
              </div>
            <br><br>
            <button id="reallocate" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{% trans 'Reallocate' %}</button>
        </form>
```

**JS**

```js
sel.on('change', function () {
  selected_site = this.value;
  var value = site_abbreviation(parseInt(selected_site));
  var options = $("#patients option");
  // on commence par masquer toutes les options
  // options.hide();
  $("#patients option[value]").filter(function() {
    return +$(this).val() != "";
  }).hide();
  // on affiches les options correspondant au site sélectionné
  var op = options.filter(function () {
    // return value == $(this).val().slice(4,6); // on retourne les options dont la valeur (numéro patient) contient le code lettre du site
    return value == $(this).val().slice(0,2); // gestion des patients pré-inclus dans un site et randomisé dans un autre centre
  }).show();

  $("#patients").val(op.eq(0).val());
  // $("#patients")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
  $("#patients option:selected").prop("selected", false);
  $("#patients option:first").attr('selected','selected').change();
})
```

Comment: You seem to be using differant HTML than in the Fiddle, could you add that to your answer also?

Answer (score 0):

Could you disable the second select box so that it can only be selected once the first dropdown has been chosen and isnt null?

so initialise the second select with "disabled" then use

```js
$(".CompName").removeAttr("disabled")
```

With the CompType onChange event?

Comment: <select name="patients" class="form-control" id="patients" required="" data-patient-url="/randomization/patient/"> 
<option selected="selected" value=""></option> 
<option value="CO/CIV-CO-001">CIV-CO-001</option> 
<option style="display: none"; value="TR/CIV-CO-002">CIV-CO-002</option> 
<option value="CO/CIV-CO-003">CIV-CO-003</option> 
<option style="display: none"; value="TR/CIV-CO-004">CIV-CO-004></option> 
<option style="display: none"; value="TR/CIV-CO-005">CIV-CO-005</option>
</select>

Comment: thanks Richard, should have read better your post, it was the easiest way to resolve my problem